# How to select rows from SQLite where digits/characters greater than some value

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have to select where the address column's size/length(character count) is greater than 12. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
String selection = "address LIKE ?";
String[] selection_args = {};
cr- content resolver
Cursor cursor = cr.query(messageUri, null, selection, selection_args, "date DESC");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
SELECT address 
FROM your_table 
WHERE LENGTH(address) > 12
```

If yes, try:

```
String selection = "LENGTH(address) > 12";
```